# How do I build a stairwell through multiple levels in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

How do I build a stairwell through multiple levels?

Comment: Just curious are these honest to goodness questions you have?

Comment: You should try to make an effort with the title of this question.

Comment: @C. Ross indeed. just discovered DF a few days ago and am working on the basics and don't have the patience to read the wiki.

Comment: @anthony Fair enough.

Comment: Adding a little more information to your question will help other people find this question when they're googling for something similar.  A good stackexchange is built on good questions, not good answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're building down:

1. Build a down [stairway](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Stair) on the first level from the designate (<kbd>d</kbd>) menu.
2. Build up-down stairways on the levels before the bottom  from the designate (<kbd>d</kbd>) menu.
3. If you have a defined "bottom" level, build an up stairway on that level from the designate (<kbd>d</kbd>) menu.

You will need to switch your view's ["z-level"](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Z-level) to build the levels.  You switch "z-levels" by using <kbd><</kbd> to go down a "z-level", and <kbd>></kbd> to go up.

Comment: perfect, thanks! I just wasn't thinking about it quite right.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Bay12 dev-log](http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/), you will be able to designate over z-levels in Dwarf Fortress version 31.26 and beyond.

Though the accepted answer's method will still work, you will be able to do the following (again, assuming you're building down):

1. <kbd>d</kbd>esignate a downward stairway on the top level (or build a stairwell if there's no dirt/stone to carve).
2. Start <kbd>d</kbd>esignating an up/down stairway one level below (change z-levels with '<' and '>')
3. Go down to the penultimate z-level, and finish designating your up/down stairway.
4. <kbd>d</kbd>esignate an upward stairway on the bottom level

Comment: nice. good to know. I need to start playing again.